# Access dll api by batch/powershell script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, dll

Through a script I need to launch a C function defined in a third party DLL.
Unfortunately the system only can run powershell or batch scripts and I cannot install python et similia.

I am quite a noob with both and I was trying to use rundll32 ([rundll](http://www.ericphelps.com/batch/rundll/)) on cmd using the following syntax:

```
rundll32 <pathToDll>,<functionName> .<StringArgument>
```

but does not seem to have any effect. The command simply ends. Am I calling it wrong?
With powershell is even worse since after googling I don't even understand if my problem is solvable.

Do I have any chances to accomplish the goal with bat or powershell? How?

Comment: Have a look at [Add-Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type)

Comment: In my opinion your question is off topic. Here we help you with an issue with your [tag:batch-file] or [tag:powershell] code, but you haven't provided any. You have told us a command which doesn't have any effect in [tag:cmd], which means it also will not have any effect in a batch script, which runs the same command in cmd.exe. You also didn't tell us is whether you tested the command, which you've not fully provided, as Administrator.

Comment: @Compo, as I said I tried the exact approach used by the most voted answer in the question you linked. I used it in cmd (not as admin, since I don't have permissions) that I suppose returns the same behavior of executing it in a batch script. However no output\action\effect is produced.

I am not fully aware of the possibilities offered by batch and powershell for the question subject: that's why it is wide.